# git-CMD loads a new pageant.exe (without any keys)

Tags: windows, git, cmd, ssh-keys, pageant

I have a strange issue when trying to clone a repository via git-CMD.

Firstly I run pageant.exe and add the required ppk file. (Then pageant.exe sits in the system tray quite happily with the ppk I gave it)

Then when I submit the git clone abc... command (using git-CMD), another pageant.exe instance gets started via git (within Process Monitor I can see two pageants and two PIDs) but of course only one of them has the ppk file.

Git isnt able to see the first running pageant, the instance with the key, it only sees the second without the key and fails. I know that pageant shouldn't load already with a key.

Pageant then shows the following error message "Couldn't load this key (unable to open file)"

Comment: Is git using a different paegent? I had a similar issue before where I had the ssh agent installed in two separate places. My powershell config opened one ssh-agent and key but git tried to use another

Comment: @Toby your right, i believe that is the issue but i'm not sure where to look to see what paegent git is pointing to... Do you know to check?

Answer (score 0):

Sooo I have been a complete FOOL!

After running Process Mon I was able to see that pageant.exe was being called where plink.exe should be called. Example below;

"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" git@blahblah "git-upload-pack 'blahblah.git'"

I checked and the environment variable was set as Pegeant.exe NOT plink.exe.